# is that possible to binding views by using variables?

Tags: ember.js

to create ember object and view dynamically such as

```
App[a] = Ember.Object.create({realName: b.name})
App[a] = Ember.View.create(
    tagName: b.tag
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{???}}'

)
```

i can not put App[a+'Widget'].realName in the handlebar template,  is that possible to do it in some other ways?  see http://jsfiddle.net/lily/qSWAh/2/

Answer (score 1):

The handlebars template will be evaluated in the context of the view at the time it is rendered. Therefore, if you want to refer to `{{realName}}` directly, you'll need to define `realName` on your view. If you want to evaluate `realName` in some other scope, say for `App`, just specify it like this: `{{App.realName}}`.

I don't fully grok the intent of your example, but you may want to do something like this to store your "widget" object on your view:

```
App[a + "Widget"] = Ember.Object.create({realName: b.name})
App[a + "View"] = Ember.View.create(
    appWidget: App[a + "Widget"]
    tagName: b.tag
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile '{{appWidget.realName}}'
)
```

Comment: awesome, thank you so much.  I try to create Ember object and view on the fly, when iterate through a json data model.